# Display message to user depending on the count of words in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, spam

I have read a file and split them into an array of words:

```
file1 = File.open("spam1.txt","rb")
file1_contents = file1.read
file1 = file1_contents.split(' ')
```

I can count the frequency of words, using a hash, and sort them according to the frequency of the word:

```
freqs1 = Hash.new(0)
file1.each { |word| freqs1[word] +=1}
freqs1 = freqs1.sort_by {|x,y| y}
freqs1.reverse!
```

Can also output the results to the user like this:

```
freqs.each{|word, freq| puts word + ' ' + freq.to_s}
```

I want to display a message to the user, if the array `file1` or hash `freqs1` contains **certain words** multiple times.

I had a (bad) idea to loop through the `freqs1` hash and display the appropriate message to the user:

```
freqs1.each{|word,freq|
    if ((word == ('business' || 'fund' || 'funds' || 'account' ||'transfer' || 'money')) && freq > 2)  || (word == 'Iraq' && freq > 1 )  then
      puts "File 1 is suspected as spam mail - suspicious word frequency"
    else
      puts "File 1 does not appear to be spam email"
    end
}
```

However this was silly of me as this acts on each element of the `hash`.

How can I display a certain message to the user if words like `business, fund, funds, account` etc appear more than twice?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to improve that final statement, try this (un-tested, but should go):

```
bad_words = %w{business fund funds account transfer money}
is_spam = freqs1.any? do |word, freq| 
  (freq > 2 && bad_words.include?(word)) || (word == 'Iraq' && freq > 1)
end

if is_spam
  puts "File 1 is suspected as spam mail - suspicious word frequency"
else
  puts "File 1 does not appear to be spam email"
end
```

[`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) will do most of the work for you, also extracting the list of bad words aids readability.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
word_filter = [
 {count: 2, words: ['business','fund','funds','account','transfer','money']},
 {count: 1, words: ['iraq']}
]

alert        = "File 1 is suspected as spam mail - suspicious word frequency"
calm_message = "File 1 does not appear to be spam email"

grouped_words = file1.group_by{|x|x}.map{|x,array|[x,array.size]}

appears_to_be_spam = grouped_words.any?{ |word,count|
  word_filter.any? do |filter|
    filter[:words].include?(word.downcase) &&  count > filter[:count]
  end
}

puts appears_to_be_spam ? alert : calm_message
```

Comment: Thanks - this works, @Nick Veys was the earlier answer so had to accept his - but I like this method.